# Why my activity not change when NFC Tag Discovered?

Tags: java, nfc

I created an activity which will detect nfc tags. When an nfc tag with the appropriate id is detected it will switch activities. But right now my activity is not responding to anything.

here is the code i wrote

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan);

   handleNfcIntent(getIntent());
   }

private void handleNfcIntent(Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            if (tag != null) {
                String nfcTagId = byteArrayToHexString(tag.getId());

                TextView tagIdTextView = findViewById(R.id.tagid);
                tagIdTextView.setText("Tag ID: " + nfcTagId);

                if (nfcTagId.equals("53:44:77:A1:00:00:01")) {
                    Intent targetIntent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(targetIntent);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Did i miss something?

Comment: What have you put in your Manifest xml? Though note just adding the right Intent items to your manifest is not a good way to detect NFC tags when your App is already running, you should use a fore ground method like `enableReaderMode` for that.

Comment: I put this <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/> in my manifest. So I have to use foreground instead of using intent filter right? Cause i want to detect NFC tags from within the app

Comment: It's solved. Thanks, i followed your instructions to use `enabledReaderMode`. But how to get rid of pop up "Choose an action" after switching activity?

Comment: I find it best user experience to use `enableReaderMode` in all activities, for any Activity that does not use NFC have any empty `onTagDiscovered`